# Magento 1.5 sort categories by name in head-navigation

Tags: magento

I try to order the categories and child-categories in the head-navigation by name. 
I found at least 3 differnet ways to do so, but none of them seems to work.

1. add "`->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)`" to Category.php
2. add "`->setOrder('name', 'asc')`" to Category.php
3. add "`->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)`" to Category.php
4. add "`->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc')`" to Category.php
5. sort with an SQL Query, may work, but its not a real option in my case

and some others not worth to notice...

For the layered-navigation i figured out to sort the array, but can't do so in the head-navigation.
I'm grateful for all kind of hints...

THX!

Answer (score 0):

That's because collection is loaded using `->load()` - after that you can't change it. Best way to sort it is by sorting it in admin with drag and drop, or if that's not an option, you have to hook on catalog collection event _load_before in
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat/Collection.php`
(if you're using flat catalog),
but that's not a proper way since it will impact display of any category listing and render your admin sorting unusable. Take your time and sort it properly in admin.

Comment: thx for the reply. Sorting it by drag'n'drop is no option either, we have more than 300 subcats, and after every re-import we would have to sort it again. As i understand your answer, if i change it in the Collection.php i can't use the normal drag'n'drop in the backend, we dont really need that function anyways, so that might be a good solution for this particular need, not in general, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: well when you reimport make sure to have a sort order number :) anyway, if you really want to sort it on db pull, find out the event name during top nav category generation (you can set a break point on line 117, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection`) and create an observer , or overwrite the collection class with your own _beforeLoad method, where you would apply the sort. There are many resources on google on how to create an observer.